# pass variable to `mutation` apollographql server

Tags: graphql, apollo, react-apollo, strapi

I am trying to pass variable to `mutation` through apollo's javascript client, however, it always returns 400 error: `[Error: Response not successful: Received status code 400]` which indicates there's something wrong with my query

below is my query:

```
const SET_ADDRESS_LASTUSED = gql`
  mutation UpdateAddress($phone: String!, $name: String!) {
    updateAddress(input: {
      where: {
        phone: $phone
      },
      data: {
        name: $name
      }
    }) {
      address {
        name
        phone
      }
    }
  }
`;
```

I am calling the mutation like this:

```
const [updateLastUsed, updateLastUsedResult] = useMutation(SET_ADDRESS_LASTUSED);

          // sometime later,
          updateLastUsed({
            variables: {
              phone: "+12345678910",
              name: "WhyICanNotChangeMyName?",
            },
          });
```

is there something wrong that I didn't notice? I'd be able to successfully mutate if I hardcode the variable like this, but of course, I can't do it this way

```
const SET_ADDRESS_LASTUSED = gql`
  mutation {
    updateAddress(input: {
      where: {
        phone: "+12345678910"
      },
      data: {
        name: "ICanChangeMyName!"
      }
    }) {
      address {
        name
        phone
      }
    }
  }
`;
```

Please help. I've been debugging pointlessly for hours... I can always pass a variable to `query` using a similar way :(

Btw, I am using Strapi Server

Thanks in advance!

Reference:
https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/api/react/hooks/
https://strapi.io/documentation/developer-docs/latest/plugins/graphql.html#graphql

Comment: you can test mutation in graphiql using 'query variables' .... prepare entire `input` in js and pass as variable

Comment: thanks! but how do I declare the `input` param? `($input: JSON!)` doesn't seem to work.. same 400 error ?

Comment: read API specs, must match BE declaration

Comment: Hey @xadm thanks a lot for the guide!! Even if it isn't clear initially as I am new to this, your comment really help! I never think it will be `updateAddressInput` like stated in the SDL hahaha

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make sure your Query (including mutation) is the same (has the same variables) as what is stated in the SDL

If you're using Strapi, there is a bug where the param of `ID` type has to be specified as `$id` cannot be something else, not sure how it gets like this but if you found 400 errors where it shouldn't be, try checking if there is any `ID` type declared not exactly as `$id`, hope it helps someone

Comment: if in API input id is type of `ID!` then variable for this id must be declared as `$id: ID!`, not `$id: ID`

Comment: @xadm do you know why it has to be `$id: ID!` and not `$addressId: ID!`, it is so weird, that should be just parameters name but it causes it to break

Comment: case? ... it should work as `$startedNameVariableCanBeAnything` is just name of variable, dynamic part, just defines dictionary element, 'consumed' at parsing step (shopify specific requirement?) ... input name (left part of `someInputId: $someVariableId`) must match (API defined input name) on 'consuming part', in query 'body'